# Jest mockImplementation on single function within module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Hi there I am just trying to use jest to jest my image min module, the issue I am having is when using imagemin it creates its own tmp folder within a child process which just screws with the path because I am using mock-fs. So all I want to do is have a single function within the module return a predetermined result which will then be passed to another function.

So far in my jest I have

```
it('Should compress jpg', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    let mock = jest.fn();
    mock.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    utility.compress = mock;

    let opts = {};
    let dest = './tmp/dest/img';
    let file = path.join(dest, 'jpeg_img.jpg');

    return utility.imageCompress(['./dummy_data/img/*.jpg'], dest, opts)
      .then(data => {
        expect(data).toEqual([]);
        expect(fs.existsSync(file)).toBe(true);
        expect(fs.statSync('./dummy_data/img/jpeg_img.jpg').size)
          .toBeLessThan(fs.statSync(file).size);
      });
  });
```

So the `utility.imageCompress` calls the `compress function`

I am exporting the function but I still get `utility.compress.mockImplementation is not a function`.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Not sure if you resolved this by now, as it's been over 2 years. Did you check that the utility.imageCompress method really calls compress? And that compress is a publicly-accessible member of utility, rather than a reference to a private function within a closure?